# crear divs, eliminar, por medio de DOM JS HTML

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Programa los siguientes botones por medio de JavaScript que realicen las siguientes funciones:

- Un botón que nos permita agregar de manera secuencial los divs.
- Un botón que nos permita eliminar todos los divs.
- Un botón que nos permita eliminar todos los divs impares.
- Un botón que nos permita eliminar el div que el usuario desee.

Tengo los botones de crear y eliminar divs, pero como elimino los especificos y los pares ?

```js
var cont = 0;

function crear() {

    var creardiv = document.createElement("div");
    cont++;
    creardiv.innerHTML = cont;
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(creardiv);


}


function borrar() {
    var borrardiv = document.getElementById("container").lastChild;
    document.getElementById("container").removeChild(borrardiv);
    cont--;

}
```

```html
<div style="border: none; background-color: blue; width:100%; height: 20px">
    <button type="button" onclick="crear()">AGREGAR</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="borrar()">BORRAR</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="borrarUno()">BORRAR ESPECIFICO</button>
</div>

<p id="container" style="border: none;"></p>
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a SO en español. Es una buena primera pregunta, pero me he tomado la libertad de mejorar el formato, ya que las primeras veces cuesta un poco hacer que tu publicación se vea como uno quiere

Comment: Pablo buenas tardes.
lo habia estado intentando con un if pero no tenia conocimiento de querySelectorAll y foreach. 
la idea de los botones es buena, la pondre asi muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo crearia un boton en cada div para eliminar.  Para eliminar los impares necesitas seleccionar todos y chequear si cada uno es impar o no.  Algo asi:

```js
var cont = 0;

    function crear() {

        var creardiv = document.createElement("div");
        cont++;
        creardiv.innerHTML = cont + " <button onclick='borrarUno(this)'>Eliminar</button>";
        document.getElementById("container").appendChild(creardiv);

    }

    function borrar() {
        var borrardiv = document.getElementById("container").lastChild;
        document.getElementById("container").removeChild(borrardiv);
        cont--;

    }
    
    function borrarUno(boton) {
      var borrardiv = boton.parentNode;
      document.getElementById("container").removeChild(borrardiv);
    }
    
    function borrarPares() {
      var divs = document.getElementById("container").querySelectorAll('div');
      divs.forEach(function(div, i) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
          document.getElementById("container").removeChild(div);
        }
      });
    }
```

```html
<div style="border: none; background-color: blue; width:100%; height: 20px">
    <button type="button" onclick="crear()">AGREGAR</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="borrar()">BORRAR</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="borrarPares()">BORRAR IMPARES</button>
</div>

<p id="container" style="border: none;"></p>
```